# How to handle extended permissions dialog

Tags: java, javascript, dialog, fbjs, restfb

I used **restfb** to check extended permissions of user. I click allow permission dialog will not pop it up again next time. However I  clicking "Don't Allow" on the permission dialogue box will bring it back up every time when this page is accessed. I don't want. I want when Clicking "Don't Allow" will stop the dialog forever. please suggest me a way

Here is my code:

Java source:

```
public boolean getCheckExtPerm() throws FacebookJsonMappingException, FacebookException {
    Integer emailPerm = getFbClient().execute("users.hasAppPermission", getFbSigSessionKey(),
            Integer.class,Parameter.with("ext_perm", "email"));
    return emailPerm == null ? false : emailPerm.equals(new Integer(1));
  }
```

View source:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var checkExtPerm = <s:property value="checkExtPerm" />;
      if (checkExtPerm == false) {
        Facebook.showPermissionDialog('email', function (perms) {
          //if (perms == "email" ) {}
        });
      }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

And for the better - what happens if the user clicks "don't allow" by mistake? Next time he should be able to allow access.

You can do this in your own application, by not triggering the dialog at all if the user has denied access.

Comment: if dialogue occur again when user click don't allow that shouldn't. facebook support method check status of dialog permission?

Comment: sorry, I did not understand your message. Could you rephrase.